# Is there a way to check a radius around a random point in order for random points to be separate from each other

Tags: python, random, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm currently creating a drawing project, where I use random to create random star points in the sky. I currently have the ability for two points to not be the same, but I would like to find a way to make it so they wouldn't land in a x radius circle. Is there any way in python to complete this

```
import turtle as t, random as r
screen=t.Screen()
screen.bgcolor("#3A3B3C")
t.speed(1)


def randomStars(y, num):
  t.penup()
  t.pensize(2)
  t.color("white")
  locations = []
  
  for x in range(num):
    repeat = True
    t.penup()
    t.seth(90)
    y_pos = starLocationY(y)
    x = starLocationX()
    while repeat == True:
      if [x,y_pos] in locations:
          y_pos = starLocationY(y)
          x = starLocationX()
      else:
        locations.append([x,y_pos])
        repeat = False
    t.goto(x,y_pos)
    t.pendown()
    t.seth(60)
    t.fd(2)
    t.fd(-2)
    t.seth(-60)
    t.fd(2)
    t.fd(-2)
    t.seth(240)
    t.fd(2)
    t.fd(-2)
    t.seth(120)
    t.fd(2)
    t.fd(-2)

randomStars(85,30)
```

p.s: I'm using trinket for the project, as required by the class, so the modules are limited

link to trinket:https://trinket.io/python/9776ba1b8a

Comment: Poisson disk sampling, e.g. https://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `any` on a generator invoking turtle's `distance()` method on the elements of your `locations` list.  Easier than it sounds:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

EXCLUSION_RADIUS = 35 # in pixels

def starLocationY(y):
    return randint(y, 190)

def starLocationX():
    return randint(-190, 190)

def randomStars(y, number):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.pensize(2)
    turtle.color('white')
    locations = []

    for _ in range(number):
        y_pos = starLocationY(y)
        x = starLocationX()

        while True:
            turtle.goto(x, y_pos)

            if any(turtle.distance(location) < EXCLUSION_RADIUS for location in locations):
                y_pos = starLocationY(y)
                x = starLocationX()
            else:
                locations.append((x, y_pos))
                break

        turtle.pendown()

        for heading in range(0, 360, 120):
            turtle.setheading(heading)
            turtle.forward(2)
            turtle.backward(4)
            turtle.forward(2)

        turtle.penup()

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('#3A3B3C')

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

randomStars(85, 20)

screen.exitonclick()
```